# $scope variable does not align with two $http.get requests

Tags: angularjs

I have the following setup:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="hlos in hloss">
    <label for="entry_hlo_{[{ $index }]}" class="control-label"><span ng-if="$first">HLOS's</span></label>
    <button class="entry_remove_button">Remove</button>
    <select id="entry_hlo_{[{ $index }]}" class="hlos" name="hlos_{[{ $index }]}" ng-model="hlos_models[$index]" ng-options="hlosa for hlosa in hlos track by hlosa"></select>
</div>
```

(Please excuse the awful variable names, im playing around with the language atm).

```
backendApp.controller('FeatureController', function ($scope, $http) {
    // ...
    $http.get('/features/1/').success(function(data) {
        $scope.hlos_models = {};
        $scope.hlos_models[0] = data['hlos']; // When the [0] assign is here, it does not work
    });
    // ...
    $http.get('/hloss/').success(function(data) {
        // Just some dummy data
        $scope.hloss[["MN","LA"], ["MN","AU"];
        $scope.hlos_models[0] = "MN"; // When the [0] assign is here it works 
    }
```

I have two sections above in the JS commented. Why when i pre-assign the ng-model (the selected field) it does not generate properly and instead puts a ? option field. When I move the statement down though it seems to work...I would imagine all of this JS get's set and generated before the rest of the template actually renders (my js files are in `<head>`).

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not completely sure what your models do, but try this:

```
backendApp.controller('FeatureController', function ($scope, $http) {
// ...

// Just some dummy data
$scope.hloss[["MN","LA"], ["MN","AU"];
$scope.hlos_models = []; // initialize, now you have the object, so you can add to it.

$http.get('/features/1/').success(function(data) {
    $scope.hlos_models.push(data['hlos']); // push data when you get it
});
// ...
$http.get('/hloss/').success(function(data) {
     $scope.hlos_models.push("MN"); // push data when you get it
}
```

Explanation: You want to assign data when you receive it, as some calls may take longer than others and are asynchronous... hence can arrive in different order.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(key, hlos) in hloss">
<label for="entry_hlo_{[{ $index }]}" class="control-label"><span ng-if="$first">HLOS's</span></label>
<button class="entry_remove_button">Remove</button>
<select id="entry_hlo_{[{ $index }]}" class="hlos" name="hlos_{[{ $index }]}" ng-model="hlos_models[key]" ng-options="hlosa for hlosa in hlos track by hlosa"></select>
```